Linux XMLint (libxml2-utils) Error in GH-Actions but works on Ubuntu in WSL
Firstly sorry this is a little code but it's a script that run inlinux and is using server applications not actively programmed software.
I have a GitHub Actions rule:
        - name: Combine XML files
        run: |
          echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > tsunamods.xml
          echo '<Catalog Name="Tsunamods Catalog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' >> tsunamods.xml
          echo '<Mods>' >> tsunamods.xml
          for file in mods/**/*.xml; do
            xmllint --format "$file" | sed '1d' >> tsunamods.xml
          done
          echo '</Mods>' >> tsunamods.xml
          echo '</Catalog>' >> tsunamods.xml

For some reason this is failing with parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document however the file it's passing is now corrected, it was incorrect with 2 space chars before the XML header,   <?xml... i have removed the 2 spaces and im still getting the same error, i have even run the file though an XMLLinter in VSCode the file is fine and correct.
I have the git branch downloaded and using WSL if i run the commands
echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>' > tsunamods.xml
echo '<Catalog Name="Tsunamods Catalog" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">' >> tsunamods.xml
echo '<Mods>' >> tsunamods.xml
for file in mods/**/*.xml; do
  xmllint --format "$file" | sed '1d' >> tsunamods.xml
done
echo '</Mods>' >> tsunamods.xml
echo '</Catalog>' >> tsunamods.xml

it works perfectly but the moment i put it on to Github it's going wrong I'm unsure what this could be. or what else to try, the action output on git is: https://github.com/tsunamods-codes/Junction-VIII-Catalogs/actions/runs/12431717323/job/34709674991?pr=32
Edit:
So the above is from the release script because it's a quick and easy way to validate every mod file is valid and merge them so i can check the output when errors occure, the actual script that is erroring is validate.sh that has a whole lot of operations to obtain specific values and test them. E.G latest_version_link=$(xmllint --xpath 'string(//Mod/LatestVersion/Link)' "$file") i did also run the validate.sh in my WSL and it also does not show this problem. i will say when this issue first popped up the validate had no problems with it, just the release failed to merge the files into the artifact generated. which is what caused me to start digging into what was going wrong. it has worked many times before this.

I dont see that quotes Github Action yaml at your link (but the workflow file you linked uses pull_request_target together with ${{ github.ref }} - think twice and then once more whether you really have a use case for that. Almost nobody does, and its a terrible, terrible footgun and has gotten multiple build environments compromised in the past through incorrectly handling arbitrary input from arbitrary 3rd parties)

@Anx so there are 2 validate and release, the validate is registered to the pull_request_target, and it only tests all the config, and then release is on commit to the main/master branch is what actually produces something, that code im using is from: https://github.com/tsunamods-codes/Junction-VIII-Catalogs/blob/master/.github/workflows/release.yml
Because it's a quick and easy way to validate all the files.
